# 1 out of 3 Docusign Users mapped in Dynamics does not have access to menu items from Dynamics 365. How do I troubleshoot this one user?

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

Working in the Dynamics 365 Sandbox env. and the Docusign Demo env.  I have 3 users, all mapped between the two systems.  1 of the users does not get the Docusign menu items displaying.

I have deleted the user in both systems and readded, but still does not work.  I have reviewed that email addresses and names match.  I have reviewed Docusign permissions are set to Admin for this user.  I have done a hard refresh of the Dynamics page in the browser.  I have called into Docusign support, but they suggested I reach out to this group as they could not assist.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan, this sort of question is better answered by opening a support ticket as we'll need to get your personal account information and ask questions specific to your case. It may or may not be relevant to the entire DocuSign community. If you don't mind doing that, you can go to https://support.docusign.com/ and do it from here.

Comment: Thank  you. I will give that a try.

Comment: I submitted a support case - https://support.docusign.com/en/cases/05125095 and I have not gotten any traction on it.  I reached back out to support and they suggested I post the support case # here.  Thanks in advance.